# error when using bean/jsp to obtain login information from the user

Tags: jsp, javabeans

I used the following code in JSP, to try and retrieve login id and password. For some reason, no value is being shown when I try to output the username value from the bean...What am I missing here?

Code for loginbean.jsp--

```
<%@ page language="Java" import="java.sql.*" %>  
<HTML> 
<HEAD><TITLE>DataBase Search</TITLE></HEAD>  
<BODY>
<jsp:useBean id="db" scope="session" class="logbean.LoginBean">
  <jsp:setProperty name="db" property="*" />

 </jsp:useBean>
<jsp:forward page="welcome.jsp">
  <jsp:param name="userName" value="<%=db.getUsername()%>" />
  <jsp:param name="password" value="<%=db.getPassword()%>" />
</jsp:forward> 
</body>
</html>
```

Code for LoginBean.java--

```
package logbean;
public class LoginBean {
  String userName="";
  String password="";
  public String getUsername() {
  return userName;
  }
  public void setUsername(String username) {
  this.userName = username;
  }
  public String getPassword() {
  return password;
  }
  public void setPassword(String password) {
 this.password = password;
  }
  }
```

Code for login.jsp--

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Taurus SEO - SEO Inspector</title>
--now there are some blocks of text -------
---code for some static blocks of text-----
---code for some static blocks of text-----
---code for some static blocks of text-----
<form name="loginform" method="post" action="welcome.jsp">
          <br><br>
           <h2>Login Authentication</h2>  <br/>

          <p/><label>User Name: <input type="text" name="username"></label>
                <p/><label>Password: <input type="password" name="password"></label>
                <p/><input type="submit" value="Login">
                <input type="reset">

          </form>
-----some more static blocks of text------
-----some more static blocks of text------
-----some more static blocks of text------
```

Finally, below is code for welcome.jsp--

```
<HTML>   
<HEAD><TITLE>Welcome</TITLE></HEAD>  
<BODY>
<br><br><br><br>
<table align="center" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
    <jsp:useBean id="db" class="logbean.LoginBean" scope="session"/> 

<h4> Just checking to see if text is being shown</h4>
 <h1>Welcome <b><%= db.getUsername()%></b></h1> 

</table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you might be missing the jsp:setProperty tag in your welcome JSP (as that's the one you're posting to).